# Postgresql Manager

Tags: postgresql

I have been working with Microsoft SQL Server since 6.5 along with other database like Oracle, MySQL and SQLite. I equally appreciate or hate all these DBMS for some point or the other.

On our forthcoming project, we are considering Postgres in the back-end. I have already started playing with it, pretty interesting for me.

I have always heard good comments on Postgres database, but I don't like the admin studio at all. While creating new a table, I hate the way of creating columns on pgAdmin by having to click add button again and again.

Are there any "Studios" for Postgres database that provide

1. more organized table creation process (spreadsheet like)
2. graphical view designer

Comment: Just a side note: tables for a production system should not be created by GUI tool. Create the approriate SQL scripts, store them in a version control system and run them against the database to create your tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with plain SQL? Writing plain SQL goes much faster than click-wait-click-wait-type-click-wait-ok-wait. You could use any tool for this, pgAdmin as well.

Open Office Base can also connect with PostgreSQL, works like MS Access. And talking about MS Access, MS Access can also connect to PostgreSQL to create tables, views, etc.

Answer (score 2):

See this official [list of Administration/Development tools](http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/1).

EMS SQL Manager seems to be a good option.

Answer (score -1):

for the graphical view of SQL queries
maybe SQLeo can Help